# Fetch a local file in javascript in a Django project

Tags: javascript, django

I have a .txt file in a folder. I am using fetch() function in JS to read that file. I need to do this in Django project. But when I call the file in fetch, Django error occurs.

(index):456 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/playbooks/8.txt 404 (Not Found)

The name of the file is 8.txt and I am calling fetch function from html page, playbooks.html Please help me with this.

Comment: See docs regarding the static files; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0):

You should configure static files in your django project and use static URL.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

After that you can access the same by loading your static files in your template.

Please refer below URL for more details.

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/